# Rails. Get params to save string to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, string, parameters

I'm new to rails and was wondering how I get params to save string to DB.
As of now the only paramater that is being saved is the last one and that one is of the "int" type.

Code below, I thank in advance for any comments!

**Controller**

```
def new
    #params['titel']
    mypage=Task.new 
    mypage.name=params['titel'] 
    mypage.completion=params['done']
    mypage.priority=params['priority']
    mypage.save

    redirect_to action: "tasks"

  end
```

**Database**

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_column :tasks, :name, :string
    add_column :tasks, :completion, :string
    add_column :tasks, :priority, :int

  end
end
```

**View**

```
<form action="/asterix" method="post">
    Name <input name="name">
    <br>
    Completion <input name="completion">
    <br>
    Priority <input name="priority">
    <br>
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you probably need to review a basic tutorial on Rails. Try: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaDhY_y8WTo

Comment: Agree you'd do well to read some basic guides. These are the official Rails Guides and I strongly recommend reading through them - you will level up your rails knowledge really quick that way: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate the links! And thanks Pradeep for the answer, that was the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Common it your mistake solve it right now**
correct your code

```
def new
#params['titel']
mypage=Task.new 
mypage.name=params['titel'] 
mypage.completion=params['done']
mypage.priority=params['priority']
mypage.save
redirect_to action: "tasks"
end
```

**to**

```
def new
#params['titel']
mypage=Task.new 
mypage.name=params[:name] 
mypage.completion=params[:completion]
mypage.priority=params[:priority]
mypage.save
redirect_to action: "tasks"
end
```

The error is due to that you used different parameter name then name used in form.